# iphone - come to the annotation when cell is clicked

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview

In my mapview project, I have passed an NSMutableArray of my custom annotation to a table view.
in tha mapview .m code:

```
MyLocation *nota =[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:name time:horario];        

            [_mapView addAnnotation:nota];   //add location to map

            [mapViewAnnotations addObject:nota];  //copy "nota" to the new array...

    }
    TablaViewController  *tablaController =[[TablaViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TablaViewController" bundle:nil];
    tablaController.locationFromMap = mapViewAnnotations;    //... then I pass array to table
```

in the table View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Locations";

    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [locationFromMap count]; i++){

        MyLocation *location = [locationFromMap objectAtIndex:i];
        //Add items
        [listOfItems addObject:location.name];
        NSLog(@" list count : %d",[listOfItems count]);
    }


}
```

where locationFromMap is a NSmtable array of custom location with some atributes like  name, subname etc.

Using :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text  = cellValue;
    return cell;
}
```

location "name" are correctly showed in the table. 
My question is how can a come back to map focusing on a concrete location when the relative row is   clicked. Perarps my method is wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Thanks for answer. i know that but  I do not Know how to point to the concrete location selected in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyLocation *loc = [locationFromMap objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MKCoordinateRegion r = MKCoordinateRegionMake(loc.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005));
    [self.mapView setRegion:r animated:YES];
}
```

(typed inline but something like this)

Comment: Thanks, It seems the right way. mapview is not defined in table view. is possibe to open my mainMapView from that method?

Comment: add it to the view somehow or push pop the view controller... please provide more info about where the two views are ....

Comment: FrontViewController *controller = [[FrontViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrontViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller._mapView selectAnnotation:loc animated:YES];
    [controller._mapView setRegion:r animated:YES];

Comment: It works! the problem is that a new map is created and I would come to previouse one. Is it possible?